# Enforce the size of DialogFragment / make it go beyond the screen

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have the following case: I need to put a a big image (that is beyond screen size) within a dialog frame, however I still need the dialog frame have around 150dp margin on top (so that title behind it would be visible). I could do this either by having the dialog go beyond the screen, or by enforcing the size of the dialog and setting its y position to some value, lets say 150. However what happens now, is that when there is no place in the screen, DialogFragment still expands as much as it can until the border of the screen (It works on the device where the screen size is big enough to hold the image full-sized), thus ignores the vertical start position y. Is there any way I could solve this problem? Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.findings_dialog, container, false);

        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        // window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

        Display display = window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams p = window.getAttributes();
        p.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE;
        p.x = 240;
        p.y = 40;
        p.height = 100;
        // p.verticalMargin = 50.0f;
        window.setAttributes(p);

        // ScrollView scv = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.findingsPopup);
        // ViewGroup.LayoutParams svcp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height - 200);
        // scv.setLayoutParams(svcp);

        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.findingsImage);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dummy_findings_picture); // TODO dummy image

        Button closeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // this.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);

        return v;
    }
}
```

and here is the xml layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/findingsPopup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="100dp"
android:minHeight="50dp" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/closeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClose"
    android:text="@string/close" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/closeButton" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/findingsImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/acute_myocarditis_cover" />
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```